# How do I horizontally center my navigation bar for desktop view and mobile view?

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to software engineering! I'm having quite some trouble horizontally aligning my navigation bar to the center for my desktop view? I'm currently learning how to utilize bootstrap! I'm sure I have to include a container div somewhere, just not sure! Any help is help! Thanks! Here is my website preview: https://frontendfoundations.marlenebarr.repl.co/

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  font-size: clamp(14px, -1rem + 8.333vw, 26px);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  padding: 20px;
}

section.alternate-background {
  background-color: #00a699;
  color: #fff;
}

main img {
  width: 100%;
}

.dark {
  color: black;
}


/* ---  Groups & Items --- */

.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
}

.item-double {
  flex: 2;
}


/* -------  Navigation ------- */

header {
  background-color: #ff385c;
  padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo {
  font-family: "Pangolin", cursive;
  font-size: clamp(24px, -1rem + 8.333vw, 72px);
  color: #fff;
}

header nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

header nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

header nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

header nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 20px 0 0;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #bdbdbd;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* -------  Search Form ------- */

form {
  border: 2px solid #ff385c;
  padding: 10px;
}

form label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

form select,
form input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 180px;
}

form button {
  background-color: #ff385c;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

form div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* -------  Footer ------- */

footer {
  background-color: #ff385c;
}

footer p {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}


/* -------  Media Query ------- */

@media all and (min-width: 480px) {
  /* ------ General ------ */
  p {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .group-lg {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  /* ------ Navigation ------ */
  header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  header div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  /* ------ Form -----*/
  form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  form div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  form button {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pangolin&family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

<header>
  <div class="logo">Thinkfulbnb</div>
  <nav>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="#stay">Stay</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#ideas">Ideas</a></li>
      <li><a href="#host">Host</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <!-- Stay -->
  <section id="stay">
    <h2>Find the perfect vacation rental</h2>
    <!-- Create a form here -->
    <form>
      <div class="form-lg">
        <label for="location">Location</label>
        <input id="location" ; type="text" placeholder="Search Destination" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-lg">
        <label for="arrive">Arrive</label>
        <input id="arrive" ; type="date" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-lg">
        <label for="depart">Depart</label>
        <input id="depart" ; type="date" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-lg">
        <label for="type">Type</label>
        <select name="type" id="type" size="1">
          <option value="apartment">Apartment</option>
          <option value="barn">Barn</option>
          <option value="castle">Castle</option>
          <option value="houseboat">Houseboat</option>
          <option value="tiny-house">Tiny House</option>
          <option value="yacht">Yacht</option>
          <option value="yurt">Yurt</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" class="form-lg">Search</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </section>

  <!-- About -->
  <section id="about" class="alternate-background">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <div class="group-lg">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="vacation-rental-pool.png" alt="Thinkfulbnb - Vacation rental pool" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="vacation-rental-inside-stone.png" alt="Thinkfulbnb - Vacation rental inside stone" />
      </div>
      <div class="item-double">
        <p>
          Fusce porta odio nunc, eget pretium massa rutrum sit amet. Etiam fringilla aliquam dapibus. Maecenas quis nisi sed turpis aliquam porttitor eget ut quam. Sed vel scelerisque ex. Duis in pharetra neque, at tempus lorem. Aenean mi magna, posuere at quam
          sed, euismod gravida neque.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Ideas -->
  <section id="ideas">
    <h2 class="dark">Ideas</h2>
    <div class="group-lg">
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Forest retreats</h3>
        <img src="forest-retreat.png" alt="Thinkfulbnb - Forest retreat" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Beaches</h3>
        <img src="beach-house.png" alt="Thinkfulbnb - Beach house" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group-lg">
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Rustic cabins</h3>
        <img src="cabin.png" alt="Thinkfulbnb - Cabin" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Pet-friendly</h3>
        <img src="pet-friendly.png" alt="Thinkfulbnb - Pet-friendly" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Host -->
  <section id="host" class=" group-lg alternate-background">
    <div class="item">
      <h2>Want to Become a Thinkfulbnb Host?</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus molestie in est id efficitur. Sed hendrerit ut turpis quis dapibus. Nam sit amet iaculis lectus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent rhoncus pellentesque eros in aliquet. Sed accumsan elit
        lacus, id ultrices libero rutrum vitae.
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li>Mauris in pellentesque ligula.</li>
        <li>Sed accumsan elit lacus, id ultrices libero rutrum vitae.</li>
        <li>Nunc vitae ex eget neque pellentesque porttitor.</li>
        <li>Cras mollis lorem sagittis sapien imperdiet blandit. Vivamus.</li>
        <li>
          Donec vehicula ipsum nisi, eu consectetur leo feugiat et. Fusce eget hendrerit mauris.
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="become-a-host.png" alt="Thinkfulbnb - Become a host" />
    </div>
  </section>
</main>

<footer>
  <p>© Thinkful</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: do you want to align the input part below the navbar, or the navbar itself? because for me the navbar is ok, but the input tag isn't centered (but asking before answering so I know answer correctly)

Comment: yes the input tag.

Comment: Thank you very much Laaouatni! Appreciate the help. @LaaouatniAnas

Answer (score 1):

[image]

add this simple CSS code, and will hopefully solve that issue in desktop version.

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

if you want, you can also add also this code on the mobile version, outside `@media`, which is also a good design on mobile!

> `justify-content` docs link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content

---

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  font-size: clamp(14px, -1rem + 8.333vw, 26px);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  padding: 20px;
}

section.alternate-background {
  background-color: #00a699;
  color: #fff;
}

main img {
  width: 100%;
}

.dark {
  color: black;
}


/* ---  Groups & Items --- */

.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
}

.item-double {
  flex: 2;
}


/* -------  Navigation ------- */

header {
  background-color: #ff385c;
  padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo {
  font-family: "Pangolin", cursive;
  font-size: clamp(24px, -1rem + 8.333vw, 72px);
  color: #fff;
}

header nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

header nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

header nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

header nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 20px 0 0;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #bdbdbd;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* -------  Search Form ------- */

form {
  border: 2px solid #ff385c;
  padding: 10px;
  /* what I added to center it */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

form label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

form select,
form input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 180px;
}

form button {
  background-color: #ff385c;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

form div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* -------  Footer ------- */

footer {
  background-color: #ff385c;
}

footer p {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}


/* -------  Media Query ------- */

@media all and (min-width: 480px) {
  /* ------ General ------ */
  p {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .group-lg {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  /* ------ Navigation ------ */
  header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  header div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  /* ------ Form -----*/
  form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  form div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  form button {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initital-scale=1" />
  <title>Vacation Rentals & Unique Homes</title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pangolin&family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">Thinkfulbnb</div>
    <nav>
      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#stay">Stay</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ideas">Ideas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#host">Host</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>
    <!-- Stay -->
    <section id="stay">
      <h2>Find the perfect vacation rental</h2>
      <!-- Create a form here -->
      <form>
        <div class="form-lg">
          <label for="location">Location</label>
          <input id="location" ; type="text" placeholder="Search Destination" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-lg">
          <label for="arrive">Arrive</label>
          <input id="arrive" ; type="date" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-lg">
          <label for="depart">Depart</label>
          <input id="depart" ; type="date" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-lg">
          <label for="type">Type</label>
          <select name="type" id="type" size="1">
            <option value="apartment">Apartment</option>
            <option value="barn">Barn</option>
            <option value="castle">Castle</option>
            <option value="houseboat">Houseboat</option>
            <option value="tiny-house">Tiny House</option>
            <option value="yacht">Yacht</option>
            <option value="yurt">Yurt</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit" class="form-lg">Search</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>

    <!-- About -->
    <section id="about" class="alternate-background">
      <h2>About</h2>
      <div class="group-lg">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="vacation-rental-pool.png" alt="Thinkfulbnb - Vacation rental pool" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="vacation-rental-inside-stone.png" alt="Thinkfulbnb - Vacation rental inside stone" />
        </div>
        <div class="item-double">
          <p>
            Fusce porta odio nunc, eget pretium massa rutrum sit amet. Etiam fringilla aliquam dapibus. Maecenas quis nisi sed turpis aliquam porttitor eget ut quam. Sed vel scelerisque ex. Duis in pharetra neque, at tempus lorem. Aenean mi magna, posuere at quam
            sed, euismod gravida neque.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Ideas -->
    <section id="ideas">
      <h2 class="dark">Ideas</h2>
      <div class="group-lg">
        <div class="item">
          <h3>Forest retreats</h3>
          <img src="forest-retreat.png" alt="Thinkfulbnb - Forest retreat" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h3>Beaches</h3>
          <img src="beach-house.png" alt="Thinkfulbnb - Beach house" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group-lg">
        <div class="item">
          <h3>Rustic cabins</h3>
          <img src="cabin.png" alt="Thinkfulbnb - Cabin" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h3>Pet-friendly</h3>
          <img src="pet-friendly.png" alt="Thinkfulbnb - Pet-friendly" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Host -->
    <section id="host" class="group-lg alternate-background">
      <div class="item">
        <h2>Want to Become a Thinkfulbnb Host?</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus molestie in est id efficitur. Sed hendrerit ut turpis quis dapibus. Nam sit amet iaculis lectus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent rhoncus pellentesque eros in aliquet. Sed accumsan elit
          lacus, id ultrices libero rutrum vitae.
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li>Mauris in pellentesque ligula.</li>
          <li>Sed accumsan elit lacus, id ultrices libero rutrum vitae.</li>
          <li>Nunc vitae ex eget neque pellentesque porttitor.</li>
          <li>
            Cras mollis lorem sagittis sapien imperdiet blandit. Vivamus.
          </li>
          <li>
            Donec vehicula ipsum nisi, eu consectetur leo feugiat et. Fusce eget hendrerit mauris.
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="become-a-host.png" alt="Thinkfulbnb - Become a host" />
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <p>© Thinkful</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```